# Decoding SQL Server Varbinary Datatype to a Java String

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, varbinary

Trying to bypass a Jboss Hibernate issue in Java where you can't handle Nvarchar SQL Server Datatypes from a stored procedure. I can't convert or cast the datatypes to varchar due to the fact we store multibyte characters, therefore, the datatype is a must. I am however, able to convert the type to varbinary in the stored procedure and decode in Java

The SQL Server Proc:

```
Convert(varbinary, Tile)  AS Title
```

On the Java side, I read the result set and the field, now encoded such as

> **UPDATED to Actual encoded:**

```
0x440065007300690067006E0020002600200050006C0061006E006E006900
```

I attempt to parse this bytearray into a string as follow:

```
            byte[] bytes = (byte[]) dataField[0]; 

            try {

                String varbinaryString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(varbinaryString);



            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The result is pretty much the intended decoded string from the Title field, only, it is decoded in this manner:

```
D e s i g n  &  P l a n n i
```

rather than the straight out put of

```
Design & Planning Director
```

Can anyone assist me in the dilemma with Java decoding a SQL Server varbinary datatype?

Thank you in advance for your help or hints.

Comment: Are you sure the text is stored in UTF-8 encoding in the varbinary field? What type is "Tile", given that you're converting your varbinary field into it? 0x4761626520697320417765736F6D65 does not look like "D e s i g n..." to me in UTF-8. Your first lowercase "e" is at byte index 3. 0x47 is a capital G, rather than a capital D.

Comment: The title field is orginally an Nvarchar on the database table, however, hibernate will not map the Nvarchar datatype from a stored procedure, so in the stored proc, I convert it to a Varbinary. I was posting an example binary, this is the actual: 0x440065007300690067006E0020002600200050006C0061006E006E006900

Comment: I'm not sure how you go from 0x440065... into 0x476162... Those just don't seem equal, even after conversion. Could you not return the raw varbinary and then just parse it as UCS-2/UTF-16 in Java directly?

Comment: I removed the first sample varbinary, the actual is this:  Convert(varbinary, Tile)  AS Title encodes to this: 0x440065007300690067006E0020002600200050006C0061006E006E006900 when Title is Design & Planning Director.

Comment: Roger. Is it not possible to just pull out the raw varbinary and convert from UCS-2/UTF-16 in Java? Why convert in the database, and I still don't know what datatype "Tile" is - I assume it's user defined?

Comment: We can't change the datatype on the database because it hold multibyte characters, so the datatype of Tile is NVARCHAR and in the Stored Proc, I'm converting it to VARBINARY. Makes sense?

Comment: Sorry, yes, makes sense. Can you not change the encoding in Java to UCS-2/UTF16 rather than UTF-8? Converting NVARCHAR to VARBINARY does not result in UTF-8, but rather UCS-2.

Comment: String varbinaryString  = new String(bytes, "UCS-2");
System.out.println(varbinaryString );                                 // I get an error "java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UCS-2"

Comment: Java should support UTF-16, which should be identical for all intents and purposes in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Mark, you shined the light and I found the solution

Answer (score 2):

Using Spring and JPA, I could not do what other had suggestion to extend the Hibernate Sql Dialect class, although, that is a good solution if you're using the hibernate cfg. I was on the right track, but you have to remember not to limit the varbinary to the inherited length of the navarchar, ie. nvarchar(30).

```
Convert(varbinary(max), Tile)  AS Title
```

That returnes the entire encoded string. Lastly, I was trying to decode UTF-8 and although it was mostly trial and error, varbinary encodes in UTF-16.

```
s = new String(bytes, "UTF-16LE");
```